# How to communicate binary data in nameko rpc?

Tags: python-3.x, nameko

It seems json is the default way for serialization data in `nameko rpc`. If I call `rpc.my_service.send(b'\x01\')`, it will raise exception `kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable`

Is there a way to send binary data in nameko rpc? eg, `pickle`. Would please give me a short example? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can serialize with `pickle` by specifying it in your config file. Simply:

```
# config.yaml
serializer: pickle
```

And

```
nameko run my_service --config config.yaml
```

If you need something more advanced you can build your own serializer and again configure the service to use it with your config file:

```
# config.yaml
serializer: my_serializer
SERIALIZERS:
    my_serializer:
        encoder: 'path.to.encode.function'
        decoder: 'path.to.decode.function'
        content_type: 'application/x-my-serializer'
```

The encode and decode functions simply take a value and return a transformed version.

Comment: this is not working. what was the version you were using?